# Listview freeze momentarily

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Activity's Listview is loaded by custom ArrayAdapter. When activity opens, top one and half listview items are seen -which is ok for the height-. However when scroll down, the moment just before the third item is seen/loaded the activity freeze momentarily. After the third item finish the loading, there will be no freeze for other items at all. What can cause the freeze?

Here is getView method (nothing suspicious i think):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView instanceof LinearLayout)
        return convertView;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_overview, parent, false);

    TextView venueName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.venueName);
    TextView requestTime = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.requestTime);
    TextView likeCount = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.likeCount);
    TextView commentCount = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.commentCount);
    TextView singerName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.singerName);
    TextView songName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.songName);

    venueName.setText(feeds.get(position).getVenue().getName());
    requestTime.setText(TimeUtil.getFeedItemRequestedTime(feeds.get(position).getRequested_at()));
    likeCount.setText(Integer.toString(feeds.get(position).getLikes()));
    commentCount.setText(Integer.toString(feeds.get(position).getComments()));
    singerName.setText(feeds.get(position).getSong().getArtist());
    songName.setText(feeds.get(position).getSong().getTitle());


    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to post some code, specifically the `getView()` of your adapter in order for us to see what your issue could possibly be.

Comment: @dcharms I added to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one, you are inflating the view every time. After the first couple of times, `convertView` will already be inflated. Also, `findViewById()` is a fairly expensive call. It is recommended to use the ViewHolder strategy to reduce the calls. Try changing to this and see if performance improves.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView instanceof LinearLayout)
        return convertView;

    View rowView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

    if (holder == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.venueName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.venueName);
        holder.requestTime = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.requestTime);
        holder.likeCount = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.likeCount);
        holder.commentCount = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.commentCount);
        holder.singerName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.singerName);
        holder.songName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.songName);
        rowView.setTag(holder);
    }

    holder.venueName.setText(feeds.get(position).getVenue().getName());
    holder.requestTime.setText(TimeUtil.getFeedItemRequestedTime(feeds.get(position).getRequested_at()));
    holder.likeCount.setText(Integer.toString(feeds.get(position).getLikes()));
    holder.commentCount.setText(Integer.toString(feeds.get(position).getComments()));
    holder.singerName.setText(feeds.get(position).getSong().getArtist());
    holder.songName.setText(feeds.get(position).getSong().getTitle());


    return rowView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView venueName, requestTime, likeCount, commentCount,
        singerName, songName;
}
```

Comment: That should optimize overall list scrolling. I think that OP performs some time-consuming operation on UI-thread. If you perform network operations on main thread, then Android with API>=11 may throw NetworkOnMainThreadException. Any other time-consuming tasks should be also done on separate worker thread. Think of implementing AsyncTask or custom Thread with queue.

Comment: That could be true as well. This will at least potentially alleviate some of the work the UI thread is already doing to handle whatever the OP is throwing at it.

Comment: I changed it ot the viewholder approach. But there is no diffirence about freezing.

Comment: Then you must be doing something else that is blocking the UI thread momentarily. Do you have any loops that get performed?